Upgrade Kernel Failure from 6.5.0 to 6.8 & 6.8.5 due to libc6, libssl3t64 and libelf1t64
I am running :

Ubuntu 22.04
Kernel 6.5.0-27-generic
Device : Lenovo Legion 7 Ryzen 5900H RTX3080

Ever since the first installation, native speakers won't work. However, wired earphones and Bluetooth audio devices work fine. There's an active thread discussing this at kernel.org, apparently many people with Lenovo Legion devices facing the same issue. From recent posts, it seems like a solution has been implemented on kernel 6.8.5. I tried to update my kernel via Mainline Kernels apps, it failed at installation. I tried with kernel 6.8, failed the same way. Here's the full failure log for 6.8
For 6.8 :
 Setting up linux-headers-6.8.0-060800 (6.8.0-060800.202403131158) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-6.8.0-060800-generic:
 linux-headers-6.8.0-060800-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.38); however:
  Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.35-0ubuntu3.6.

and for 6.8.5 :
 Unpacking linux-modules-6.8.5-060805-generic (6.8.5-060805.202404101135) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-6.8.5-060805-generic:
 linux-headers-6.8.5-060805-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.38); however:
   Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.35-0ubuntu3.6.
 Unpacking linux-modules-6.8.5-060805-generic (6.8.5-060805.202404101135) ...
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of linux-headers-6.8.5-060805-generic:
  linux-headers-6.8.5-060805-generic depends on libc6 (>= 2.38); however:
   Version of libc6:amd64 on system is 2.35-0ubuntu3.6.
  linux-headers-6.8.5-060805-generic depends on libelf1t64 (>= 0.144); however:
   Package libelf1t64 is not installed.
  linux-headers-6.8.5-060805-generic depends on libssl3t64 (>= 3.0.0); however:
   Package libssl3t64 is not installed.

Both seem to have dependency issue with package libc6 (>= 2.38), however according to these threads, upgrading libc6 is a huge mistake and people are strongly advise against it :

How to install a libc6 version >= 2.29?
Whole system is broken after failed libc6 upgrade attempt

Moreover, with 6.8.5, I can't even find package libssl3t64 or libelf1t64 for Ubuntu. They do exist for Debian though, but would like some insight before possibly bricking my machine. In the end, I am not sure what else to look for from the log. I just want to upgrade my kernel to make my speakers work. Any suggestions ?

May be you can test the recently release 24.04-beta from a USB. It should have kernel 6.8 by default with all the dependencies worked out.

Ditch Ubuntu? " upgrading libc6 is a huge mistake " 100% and that is why I would use Debian instead of Ubuntu. 6.8,5 was released 3 days ago. Ubuntu is always a bit behind pf Debian. If you really need this I would switch to debian. Or wait for Ubuntu to catch up. 24.04 will have 6.8 so you would need to wait for 24.10 probably Though there will probably be a 6.8.5 before that and you could then install it in 24.04

OH the DEB is here https://kernel.ubuntu.com/mainline/v6.8.5/  Use https://9to5linux.com/you-can-now-install-linux-kernel-6-8-on-ubuntu-heres-how  to install it!!!!!!!  maybe it will work out  :)

I only know to compile the mainline kernel myself if I want to use it on an older Ubuntu version. I am using mainline kernel 6.9-rc3 right now on Ubuntu 20.04. Also, running the kernel doesn't always need to use the headers stuff, just try it.

@Rinzwind Ubuntu is based-on Debian, but it is not "behind", 24.04 is already released for Ubuntu as well. In fact, Ubuntu does have faster release circle than Debian. So, switching distro is not a solution. Upgrading is not what I am looking for as well at the moment, I have too many libraries and codes for my work depend on 22.04. Migrating right when it is just released is not ideal, most of my code for work will break.

@mikewhatever I have been debating on upgrading since most of my work using libraries that depend heavily on 22.04. I doubt many libraries will catch up, even in the next 4-6 months. But testing on a live-USB is a great idea ! I have Ventoy at hand and can just test if the speakers works. However, I am still open to any solutions to upgrade my kernel because I am 3 major revisions behind and that's a bad news.

Ubuntu 24.04 should have libc 2.39 and kernel 6.8. That said, Ubuntu usually goes for stabler, rather than newer. If you always need the latest versions, try Arch Linux.
